# how to assign matches to two lists of unordered elements

Tags: python, list, match

I need to find an efficient algorithm for assigning pairwise matches between elements in two lists (of same size). Sorry, but I could not formulate the problem in a more well defined mathematical language, so I will illustrate it with an example.

Assume I have two lists of objects:

```
list1 = [objA, objB, objC]

list2 = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

and I know that:

```
objA "matches" object obj1

objB "matches" objects obj1, obj2 and obj3

objC "matches" obj1 and obj3
```

So I would like to pair matching elements in such a way that no object from list2 appears more than once.
For the above example, I would like to construct the pairs:

```
(objA,obj1), (objB, obj2), (objC,obj3)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: what is the rule for 2 objects to match?

Comment: Your knowledge should be mapped in some way inside your program, otherwise you could just zip the two lists given that *you know* it's fine.

Comment: How do you "know" what matches what? is that information available in some way?

Comment: The information is encoded in a (python) dictionary: {objA : [obj1], objB : [obj1,obj2,obj3], objC : [obj1,obj3]}. The complication is that the matching is defined if obj_a "is contained" within obj_i. Hence objA == obj1 and objA == obj2 DOES NOT imply obj1 == obj2. I hope this clarifies the questions.